# How to setup new midtrans client payment gateaway in python

Tags: python, payment-gateway

i have download new midtrans client api from github, but redirect link from midtrans snap api redirect to veritrans.
What should i do to change the redirect link?

Answer (score 1):

To setup the python midtrans client you should change the redirect url directly from the package. This issue was already solved in [this github link](https://github.com/Midtrans/midtrans-python-client).